# По-разному устанавливается cookie: с точкой и без неё. Почему?

Tags: php, apache, cookie, сессия, домен

При авторизации устанавливаю куку пользовательскую и сессионную:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", $domain, False, True);
session_start();
setcookie("hash", $hash, time()+60*60*24*30, '/', $domain, False, True);
```

При этом значение `Host` у обеих установленных кук не содержит точки перед доменом.

Когда сессия теряется при срабатывании дефолтного чистильщика старых сессий на сервере, сессия перезапускается с перезаписью и сессионной куки, и куки с hash:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", $domain, False, True);
session_start();
setcookie("hash", $hash, time()+60*60*24*30, '/', $domain, False, True);
```

При этом старые куки не удаляются, но добавляются две новые куки: сессионная и hash с точками перед доменом в значении `Host`. Итого в браузере оказывается хранящимися две сессионные куки и две hash-куки. На localhost такого поведения нет, это происходит только на сервере.

Иерархия:

Сайт работает по принципу единой точки входа, при авторизации файл `user/enter.php` подгружает `require("system/auth.php");` при обновлении сессии файл `public/index.php` подгружает тот же `require("system/auth.php");`

Прошу совета, в чем причина такого поведения и как его избежать?

Comment: Вы в `$domain` посмотрите при установке в обоих случаях, а то может действительно значения разные.

Comment: Еще раз перепроверил. Значение $domain устанавливается один раз в корневом index.php (на который идет перенаправление из .htaccess) и больше нигде не перезаписывается.

Comment: в таком случае - надо следить за переменной  $domain - следить за тем что бы она удовлетворяла вашим требованиям, а как вы будете следить - регуляркой точку добавлять или урезать ее - ваше дело

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обнаружил причину такого поведения. Может быть, кому-нибудь пригодится:

Контролировать параметры установки куки можно либо в настройках [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.file.php), либо через [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", $domain, False, True);
session_start();
```

В моем случае в одном месте было пропущено `session_set_cookie_params()` и сервер устанавливал куку с параметрами `secure` и `httponly` по умолчанию и без точки, поскольку $domain явно не указывался. Схожая ситуация была и с `hash`, т.е. пропущено явное указание домена.